# Can't install image acquisition package on octave windows7

Tags: image-processing, package, octave, windows-7-x64

there I am using ***octave*** on ***windows7*** machine and unable to install ***image-acquisition*** package using command **:**

```
>> pkg install -forge image-acquisition
```

and it shows **error**

> system: unable to start subprocess for '"gzip -d -c "D:\Users\hello\image-acquisition-0.2.2\image-acquisition-0.2.2.tar.gz" | tar xf - 2>&1"'
>   **error:** called from
>       unpack at line 248 column 20
>       untar at line 47 column 5
>       install at line 81 column 9
>       pkg at line 437 column 9

### version

```
>> version
```

> 4.4.0

Comment: How have you installed GNU Octave? And btw, image-acquisition will only work on systems with v4l2 (typically GNU/Linux systems), see https://octave.sourceforge.io/image-acquisition/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your installation fails is, that the [image-acquisition](https://octave.sourceforge.io/image-acquisition/index.html) package for octave is not implemented for windows systems.

Comment: Is there a workaround? I am new to Octave (and Matlab).

Comment: Your could try to find someone who is willing to implement image acquisition on windows...